# Generate tritvectors subject to specific conditions

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinations

I am looking to generate all possible combinations of $n$ trits (i.e. taking the values $\{0,1,2\}$) subject to some rules. The trits are labels of nodes arranged either in a line graph or in a ring graph, where each trit/node thus has two neighbouring trits/nodes, or just one if they are the end nodes within the line.

If we label the nodes using their index, i.e. the nodes are $\{1,2,....,n-1, n\}$, and the trits are then $\{t_{1},t_{2},....,t_{n-1},t_{n}\}$, and the neighbourhood of node $i$ is $N_{i}$ (which is thus either $\{i-1,i+1\}, \{i+1\}$ or $\{i-1\}$; everything modulo $n$), the rules that the trits are subject to are:

- Any neighbour of a node with value $1$ or $2$ must either have the same value, or take the value $0$. That is, if $t_{i} = 1$ then $t_{j} \not = 2$ $\forall j \in N_{i}$, and, redundantly, vice versa.
- Left-right symmetry is not allowed, in that if the tritvector $\overrightarrow{t} = \{t_{1},t_{2},...,t_{n}\}$ is a valid combination, then the reversed tritvector $\overrightarrow{t'} = \{t_{n},t_{n-1},...,t_{1}\}$ is not a valid combination. It doesn't really matter which of the two is chosen to be the valid one, as long as there's just one.
- **In the case that the nodes are ordered in a ring**, any cyclic permutation of the node labels is also not allowed. That is, if the tritvector $\overrightarrow{t} = \{t_{1},t_{2},...,t_{n}\}$ is a valid combination, then tritvector $\overrightarrow{t''} = \{t_{n},t_{1},t_{2},...,t_{n-1}\}$ is not a valid combination. This extends to whatever number of 'rotations'/cyclic permutations.

I would like to be able to generate all valid combinations, eventually in python - for both the line and the ring separately. I want to check something for every of these, and want to perform a full search through all possible valid combinations. To do this, I believe I will need some sort of closed-form expression from which I can generate the valid tritvectors - I would also like to be able to create a `python generator` object for memory considerations.

As a follow-up or bonus question, I would like to be able to calculate the total number of valid combinations for a given $n$. This is not a necessity (I can just loop through all elements untill it reaches the last) but it would be nice to know in advance how many there are going to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ignore the reflection/rotation conditions, and let $a_n$ be the number of ternary strings of length $n$ with no $1$'s adjacent to any $2$'s, then
$$
a_n=3a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}\tag1
$$
with bases cases $a_0=1,a_1=3,a_2=7$. Here is the proof: let $a_n^0$ be the number of length $n$ sequences whose last entry is $0$, and similarly for $a^1_n$ and $a^2_n$ for ending with $1$ or $2$. It is easy to see that
$$
\begin{aligned}
a_n^0&=a_{n-1}^0+a_{n-1}^1+a_{n-1}^2\\
a_n^1&=a_{n-1}^0+\qquad\;+a_{n-1}^2\\
a_n^2&=a_{n-1}^0+a_{n-1}^1\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Letting $\def\a{{\bf a}}\a_n$ be the column vector $[a_n^0\;\;a_n^1\;\;a_n^2]^{\top}$, then the above system of equations is equivalent to the matrix equation $\a_n=M\a_{n-1}$, for a zero-one matrix $M$. Iterating that recurrence, $\a_n=M^n\a_0$. You can find the characteristic polynomial of $M$ to be $\lambda^3-3\lambda^2+\lambda+1$, which by Cayley-Hamilton implies $M^n-3M^{n-1}+M^{n-2}+M^{n-3}=0$ for all $n$. Right multiplying by $a_0$, you get $\a_n=3\a_{n-1}-\a_{n-2}-\a_{n-3}$, which implies $(1)$.

You can solve the linear recurrence in $(1)$ exactly, and find that
$$
a_n=\tfrac12\Big((1+\sqrt{2})^{n+1}+(1-\sqrt{2})^{n+1}\Big)\approx 1.207(1+\sqrt{2})^n
$$
Then, letting $\ell_n$ be the number of linear arrangements up to reflection,
$$
\ell_n\approx \tfrac12 a_n
$$
This will be a very good approximation for $n$ sufficiently large, in that the error is on the order of $(1+\sqrt{2})^{n/2}$, which is negligible compared to $a_n$. The exact answer is $\frac12(a_n+p_n)$, where $p_n$ is the number of palindromes with no $1$'s next to any $2$'s.

Letting $c_n$ be the number of cyclic arrangements up to rotation and reflection, then
$$
c_n\approx C\cdot {1\over 2n} \cdot a_n 
$$
for some constant $C$. To get the exact answer, you would need to use Burnside's lemma.

I wrote a python generator for both cases: https://replit.com/@mearnest/Ternary-strings-avoiding-1-2#main.py.

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for the code which works wonderfully. For my own edification, I'm trying to arrive at the same recursion relation as yours. $a_{n}$ can be interpreted as 'all previous ternary strings with an extra $0$ (i.e. $a_{n-1}$), plus all previous strings that do not finish at a $2$ with an extra $1$ or all previous strings that do not finish at a $1$ with an extra $2$. These last two contributions ought to be equal, but so far I'm failing to see how exactly either of these, I guess, takes the value $a_{n-1} - \frac{a_{n-2} + a_{n-3}}{2}$.

Comment: @JSdJ I have included a proof.